# Android/iOS application security testing checklist

Tags: penetration-test, mobile, android, ios, vulnerability

According to OWASP, we have a list of [top ten mobile application vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#tab=Top_10_Mobile_Risks).

But we are damn sure that the number of vulnerabilities on mobile apps, especially android apps are far more than listed here. And also I couldn't find a comprehensive checklist for either android or iOS penetration testing anywhere in the internet. If anyone have such a list with mobile application vulnerabilities and their testing methodologies please share here. Anything like a link to any such sources are also entertained.

Comment: You are right! most of them are Android devices' problems. We need checklist for iOS. We also need something more practicable. Not just top level guide.

Comment: @Robert Yi Jiang Yep! The oasam project seems interesting as kinunt mentioned :)

Comment: It is for Android. iOS is much more secure than Android.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a project called OASAM that aims to define a methodology to test Android devices.

You can find it here: http://oasam.org/en

The guide has the following sections:

1. OASAM-INFO:  Information Gathering:  Information gathering and attack surface definition.
2. OASAM-CONF: Configuration and Deploy Management: Configuration and deploy assessment.
3. OASAM-AUTH: Authentication: Authentication assessment.
4. OASAM-CRYPT:  Cryptography: Cryptography use assessment.
5. OASAM-LEAK: Information Leak: Confidential information leak assessment.
6. OASAM-DV: Data Validation:User entry management assessment.
7. OASAM-IS: Intent Spoofing: Intent reception management assessment.
8. OASAM-UIR: Unauthorized Intent Receipt:Intent resolution assessment.
9. OASAM-BL Business Logic: Application business logic assessment.

Answer (score 6):

AppSec has a nice [list](https://appsec-labs.com/android_attacks-tests/):

- Reverse Engineering the Application Code
- Testing for Common Libraries and Fingerprinting
- Enumeration of Application Known Controllers
- Information Disclosure by Logcat
- Hidden Secrets in the Code
- Storing Sensitive Data on Shared Storage (exposed to all applications without any   restrictions)
- Cryptographic Based Storage Strength
- Content Providers Access Permissions
- Content Providers SQL Injection
- Privacy and Metadata Leaks
- User Propriety Data in Logcat
- Technical Valuable Data in Logcat
- Exposed Components and Cross Application Authorization
- Permissions & Digital Signature Data Sharing Issues
- Clipboard Separation
- Public Intents and Unauthenticated Data Sources
- Public Intents and Authorization Flaws
- Code Puzzling and Abusing Application State
- Race Conditions, Deadlocks and Concurrency Threats
- In Device Denial of Service attacks
- Exposing Device Specific Identifiers in Attacker Visible Elements
- Exposure of Private User Data to Attacker Visible Components
- Tracking Application Installations in Insecure Means
- Tap Jacking
- Client Side based Authorization Decisions
- Bypassing business logic
- WebView Security
- Exposing External Java Interfaces in WebViews DOM
- JavaScript Execution Risks at WebViews
- Code Signing
- Loading Dynamic DEX onto Dalvik
- Abusing Dynamic Code Execution Decisions
- Stack Based Buffer Overflows
- Heap Based Buffer Overflows
- Object Lifetime Vulnerabilities (Use-after-free, double free’s)
- Format Strings Vulnerabilities
- NDK Exposed Code Secrets
- Integer Overflows
- Integer Underflows
- Insecure Transport Layer Protocols
- TLS Authenticity Flaws
- TLS Weak Encryption
- Bypassing TLS Certificate Pinning
- TLS Known Issues – CRIME, BREACH, BEAST, Lucky13, RC4, etc…
- Disable certificate validation
- Using Insecure Authentication Vectors (IMEI, MAC, etc..)
- Cross Application Authentication
- Local Authentication Bypass Threats
- Client Side Based Authentication Flaws
- Client Side Authorization Breaches
- Shared User Resources
- Excessive Permissions
- Disclosure of Privileged Data to Public Resources

Answer (score 6):

The OWASP Mobile Security Testing Guide -- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#tab=Mobile_Security_Testing
UPDATE -- here -- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N7zMXlFHtWfc00xa6lRHnVB60U4BZO4SbUrWYMbojVM/edit?usp=sharing

(a link to the GDocs file as well as a huge overview)

Comment: Recently they have updated this. When I posted the question for the first time their documentation wasn't like this :)

Comment: You can see the whole history of when they posted what because it's MediaWiki

Comment: there's some new stuff coming up on this website -- https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Pinning_Cheat_Sheet.html